# How users are getting older versions of apk?

Tags: google-play

my x version is on full rollout on play store but my new users are still downloading the older versions.
Whenever we are uploading any new version on play store, older version automatically deactivate or we need to do it manually?

Answer (score 0):

No, we don't need to deactivate the older versions. It takes sometimes for your new release to be updated in users' Play Store app (sometimes it can take up to several days). It is normal, you do not need to be worried to much. After users download your older version(s), they will be prompted to update your app to newer version soon.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one version of the application in your release, then that is enough for users to move to the new version.

However, you will often see a few installs of old versions. One is P2P app sharing. Currently ShareIt, Xender and Files Go when they P2P share versions of apps can use Google Play to install them ([see the blog post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/10/offline-p2p-installs-beta.html)). These will appear in your statistics as installs of old versions, but the users will eventually get updated. The security metadata has an expiry time, so versions older than 3 months will never be installed.

You might also see old versions being installed for users who had an old version and do backup of one phone and restore to a new phone.